# Decide which route inside <Switch /> to render based on a condition

Tags: react-router, react-loadable

I have two kinds of routes: a `user` and a `project` route. The `user` route is a top-level URL resource, while `project` belongs to a `user`. For example: `/users/1/foo` and `/users/1/projects/2/bar`.

I want to show a component specific to a user route only when the route doesn't contain `/projects/:id`, and project-specific component whenever it does.

Trying the following will in both cases load the `/users/:id` route:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/users/:id" component={...} />
  <Route path="/users/:id/projects/:projectId" component={...} />
</Switch>

<Switch>
  <Route path="/users/:id/projects/:projectId" component={...} />
  <Route path="/users/:id" component={...} />
</Switch>
```

Normally, this could be achieved very easily by having a component with a conditional showing either component, however my requirement is that I want to load the user- and project-specific components dynamically (the imports being handled by `webpack` and `react-loadable` automatically), so it looks like I'd need a Route-level solution, or perhaps something custom using `react-loadable`.

**EDIT**
The issue was that I was specifying the wrong path for the Route. Doing what I wanted is possible as long as I put the more specific (`project`) route first inside a `<Switch />`

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is `exact`.

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/users/:id" component={...} />
    <Route exact path="/users/:id/projects/:projectId" component={...} />
</Switch>
```

From the v4 [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route/exact-bool).

Comment: Hi! The exact won't work for me, because my routes can be `/users/1/foo` or `/users/1/bar` - and in that case the component should show as well. I actually figured out the that config I showed in my question would work. I was simply specifying the wrong path and will need to place the more specific route first. Cheers!